# Labels for cluster centers in Python sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When utilizing the sklearn class `sklearn.cluster` for K-means clustering, a fitted k-means object has 3 attributes, including a numpy array of cluster centers (centers x features) named `cluster_centers_`. However, these centers don't have an attached label.

My question is: are the centers (rows) in `cluster_centers_` ordered by the label value? That is, does row 1 correspond to the center for the cluster labeled 1? Or are they placed in the array randomly? A pointer to any documentation would be more than sufficient.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I couldn't find the documentation but yes it is ordered by cluster.

So:

```
kmeans.cluster_centers_[0] = centroid of cluster 0
```